# How to trigger code once after update in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Forms application for iOS and Android which is about to recieve som larger changes. To migrate the current data stored in the app, I would like to run some "migration code" as soon as the app is updated - is this possible?

Is there any event or alike in Xamarin.Forms which allows me to **run a piece of migration code only once when the app has been updated?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leverage [Xamarin.Essentials' Version Tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/version-tracking?context=xamarin/xamarin-forms) API:

Here are some of information you will be provided with:

```
// First time ever launched application
var firstLaunch = VersionTracking.IsFirstLaunchEver;

// First time launching current version
var firstLaunchCurrent = VersionTracking.IsFirstLaunchForCurrentVersion;

// First time launching current build
var firstLaunchBuild = VersionTracking.IsFirstLaunchForCurrentBuild;

// Current app version (2.0.0)
var currentVersion = VersionTracking.CurrentVersion;
```

You can use firstLaunchCurrent bool for your scenario provided your updated app's *string* version has been increased, otherwise use firstLaunchBuild bool because increasing the build number(which is an int type) is required for updated apps.

Answer (score 2):

The most common approach to doing this is to set a flag (in the db or file system, or using Properties or the Settings Plugin) after your update is done, or to base the update logic on your app's version number.